# IntelliJ always builds for Java 1.7

Tags: intellij-idea

I have my ANT configured to use a 1.6 JDK,  my ENV variables JRE_HOME and JDK home both point to JDK6.
If I modify the JDK 6 folder name in my File explorer then my ANT build fails,  cannot find JDK,  so I know for sure it is using the correct JDK.  However the generated clases are always compiled against java 1.7.  Why i this?  (My generated classes will only run on a 1.7 jre,  I get version error if i run on a 1.6 JRE) All my project/module settings are pointing to 1.6 jdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like not all of your Module/Project settings point to JDK 1.7 or you are using **in-process** javac option in `Settings` | `Compiler` while running IDEA under JDK 1.7.

Also check additional javac command line options, it should not contain options like `-source 1.7 -target 1.7`.